# Solving polynomial 3rd order polynomial equation for intensity mapping

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a concentration based gas dispersion model and I am having some 
issues with the data analysis. I currently have a model that outputs Concentration formula as a function of x,y,z. I was wondering if it was possible to write a program that would find all of the points (x,y,z) that output a concentration value greater than 0. For example

My equation looks something like this (The equation is a lot more complicated, but you see what I mean).

> Concentration Value (ppm) = C(x,y,z) = (2*X) + (5*Y) + 6(Z^2)

and I am looking for all int plots (so x, y, and z) that return a concentration value of greater than 0 as well as the corresponding output value.

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your range of int's for x, y and z?

Comment: `x, y, z > 0` gives you a handful of solutions :)

Comment: id like them to be user set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but try this simple approach, which uses the `[-10,10)` values range for `x`,`y` and `z`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
        int x1 = -10, x2 = 10,
            y1 = -10, y2 = 10,
            z1 = -10, z2 = 10;

        for (int ix = x1; ix < x2; ix++)
        {
            for (int iy = y1; iy < y2; iy++)
            {
                for (int iz = z1; iz < z2; iz++)
                {
                    var result = (2 * ix) + (5 * iy) + 6 * (Math.Pow(iz, 2));
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("x {0} y {1} z {2} : {3}", 
                            ix, iy, iz, result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jhogg, this should work if you're just looking for integer x,y,z values, but if you are looking for decimals you will need to post the specific equation so that you can find a more clever solution that doesn't require looping through the range of all real numbers.

Comment: I think thats what im looking for. Thank you, thats a lot easier than I expected.